# JavaScript Reload Page Script

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function show_confirm(){
                var r=confirm("Hello or Goodbye?");
                if (r==true){
                    alert("Hello");
                    window.location.replace("http://www.google.com/");
                } else {
                    alert("Goodbye");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="show_confirm()" value="Show a confirm box" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm learning JavaScript, and I'm using W3School's Tryit Editor, and this code wasn't working like I hoped. I want it to redirect me to google after someone hits 'OK' twice, but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me out?

Comment: use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and [never use W3Schools as reference](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: I just tried it in notepad, saved to my desktop, and it works... As I thought it should.

Comment: Tip: never test equality to true, just use the boolean variable/expression!

Comment: It works fine fine, than what is problem ?

Comment: If i were working fine why would I post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Try-It Editor is using an IFrame. When I try it in Chrome and open up my developer console, I get the following error:

`Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.`

This is because what your code is *trying* to do is change the location of the current frame, not the entire page.

You can do one of three things:

- Try your HTML outside of an IFrame and you should get it to work then.
- Try using `window.top.location.replace("http://www.google.com/");` instead of `window.location`
- If you must change the location of an iframe with JavaScript, you'll have to either do so *outside* of the frame or make sure it stays within the same domain as the parent document. (You'll notice that `window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com")` works just fine.)